# Can BigQuery API overwrite existing table/view with create_table() (tables insert)?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the [Python client create_table() function](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.create_table) which calls the underlying [tables insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert). There is an `exists_ok` parameter but this causes the function to simply ignore the create if the table already exists. The problem with this is that when creating a view, I would like to *overwrite* the existing view SQL if it's already there. What I'm currently doing to get around this is:

```
if overwrite:
    bq_client.delete_table(view, not_found_ok=True)

view = bq_client.create_table(view)
```

What I don't like about this is there are potentially several seconds during which the view no longer exists. And if the code dies for whatever reason after the delete but before the create then the view is effectively gone.

**My question**: is there a way to create a table (view) such that it overwrites any existing object? Or perhaps I have to detect this situation and run some kind of `update_table()` ([patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch))?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite an existing table, you can use `google.cloud.bigquery.job.WriteDisposition` class, please refer to [official documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.html).

You have three possibilities here: `WRITE_APPEND`, `WRITE_EMPTY` and `WRITE_TRUNCATE`. What you should use, is `WRITE_TRUNCATE`, which overwrites the table data.

You can see following example here:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas

client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = "<YOUR_PROJECT>.<YOUR_DATASET>.<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>"

records = [
    {"artist": u"Michael Jackson", "birth_year": 1958},
    {"artist": u"Madonna", "birth_year": 1958},
    {"artist": u"Shakira", "birth_year": 1977},
    {"artist": u"Taylor Swift", "birth_year": 1989},
]
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
    records,
    columns=["artist", "birth_year"],
    index=pandas.Index(
        [u"Q2831", u"Q1744", u"Q34424", u"Q26876"], name="wikidata_id"
    ),
)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("artist", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        bigquery.SchemaField("wikidata_id", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)
job.result()

table = client.get_table(table_id)
```

Let me know if it suits your need. I hope it helps.

UPDATED:

You can use following Python code to update a table view using the client library:

```
client = bigquery.Client(project="projectName")
table_ref = client.dataset('datasetName').table('tableViewName')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
table.view_query = "SELECT * FROM `projectName.dataset.sourceTableName`"
table = client.update_table(table, ['view_query'])
```

Comment: "write disposition" is part of creating a load job to generate a table. I'm specifically asking about the API command that creates a table (since I'm using it to create a view).

Comment: I've updated my question with updating view code. Also you can take a look [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/tables.html#updating-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

Hope this may help!

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

clientBQ = bigquery.Client()

def tableExists(tableID, client=clientBQ):
    """
    Check if a table already exists using the tableID.
    return : (Boolean)
    """
    try:
        table = client.get_table(tableID)
        return True
    except NotFound:
        return False


if tableExists(viewID, client=clientBQ):
    print("View already exists, Deleting the view ... ")
    clientBQ .delete_table(viewID)


view = bigquery.Table(viewID)
view.view_query = "SELECT * FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET_NAME.TABLE_NAME`"

clientBQ.create_table(view)
```